# Custom ArrayAdapter for binding to ListView recursively

Tags: android, listview, xamarin.android

I have a hierarchial list of categories which I wanted to render in a layout with recursive ListView using a custom array adaptor.  Each category can have subcategories to any depth.

To keep it simple, for now assume category only has title and array of subcategories (again just title).  In the sample below, there are 3 toplevel categories.  The first top level category has 3 sub categories.  The first subcategory in turn has 3 subcategories.

```cs
    public class MyListActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.my_list);


            List<CategoryItem> categories = new List<CategoryItem>();


            categories.Add(new CategoryItem("Category 1"));
            categories.Add(new CategoryItem("Category 2"));
            categories.Add(new CategoryItem("Category 3"));

            categories[0].Children.Add(new CategoryItem("Sub 11"));
            categories[0].Children.Add(new CategoryItem("Sub 12"));
            categories[0].Children.Add(new CategoryItem("Sub 13"));


            categories[0].Children[0].Children.Add(new CategoryItem("Sub Sub 111"));
            categories[0].Children[0].Children.Add(new CategoryItem("Sub Sub 112"));
            categories[0].Children[0].Children.Add(new CategoryItem("Sub Sub 113"));

            ListView listView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listView1);

            CategoryAdaptor adaptor = new CategoryAdaptor(Android.App.Application.Context, categories);

            listView.Adapter = adaptor;

            // Create your application here
        }
    }
```

Here is the custom adapter for listView.  Note that it is calling another listview recursively in GetView

```cs
    public class CategoryAdaptor : ArrayAdapter<CategoryItem>
    {

        string TAG = "CategoryAdaptor";

        List<CategoryItem> categories;
        Context context;

        public CategoryAdaptor(Context context, List<CategoryItem> categories) : base(context, 0, categories)
        {
            this.context = context;
            this.categories = categories;
        }

        public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            Log.Debug(TAG, "GetView called for position - " + position);

            //For now ignore convertView...which is perfectly legal
            var listItem = LayoutInflater.From(context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.category_list_item, parent, false);

            Log.Debug(TAG, "Binding - " + categories[position].Title);

            listItem.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1).Text = categories[position].Title;


            if (categories[position].Children.Count > 0)
            {
                var childView = listItem.FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.childItems);
                var childAdaptor = new CategoryAdaptor(context, categories[position].Children);
                childView.Adapter = childAdaptor;
            }


            return listItem;

        }

    }
```

Main Layout contains a listview. I also have removed all formatting on the layout files so that the code is less noisy.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ListView
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="250px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listView1" />



</LinearLayout>
```

Items in list view have the following template as set by the custom adapter.  Note that this has another listview so that children for each category can be displayed recursively.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:id="@+id/textView1" />
    <ListView
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="250px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/childItems" />
</LinearLayout>
```

However, the code does not seem to output intended results.  Only the first item in subcategories are rendered as shown in image below.  See that it is missing 2 nd and 3rd subcategories. Any pointers would be really appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After setting up the Adapter of the ListView, the height of the ListView is recalculated according to the subitems of the ListView, so we need to set the height to the ListView as `LayoutParams`.

You can try the following code:

class Utility

```
public class Utility
{
    public static void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView)
    {
        {
            if (listView.Adapter == null)
            {
                // pre-condition
                return;
            }

            int totalHeight = listView.PaddingTop + listView.PaddingBottom;
            for (int i = 0; i < listView.Count; i++)
            {
                View listItem = listView.Adapter.GetView(i, null, listView);
                if (listItem.GetType() == typeof(ViewGroup))
                {
                    listItem.LayoutParameters = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
                }
                listItem.Measure(0, 0);
                totalHeight += listItem.MeasuredHeight;
            }

            listView.LayoutParameters.Height = totalHeight + (listView.DividerHeight * (listView.Count - 1));
        }
    }
}
```

And use it in `CategoryAdaptor` like this:

```
public class CategoryAdaptor: ArrayAdapter<CategoryItem>
{
    string TAG = "CategoryAdaptor";

    List<CategoryItem> categories;
    Context context;

    public CategoryAdaptor(Context context, List<CategoryItem> categories) : base(context, 0, categories)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.categories = categories;
    }

    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        Log.Debug(TAG, "GetView called for position - " + position);

        //For now ignore convertView...which is perfectly legal
        var listItem = LayoutInflater.From(context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.category_list_item, parent, false);

        Log.Debug(TAG, "Binding - " + categories[position].Title);

        listItem.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1).Text = categories[position].Title;


        if (categories[position].Children.Count > 0)
        {
            Log.Info("123456","");

            var childView = listItem.FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.childItems);
            var childAdaptor = new CategoryAdaptor(context, categories[position].Children);
            childView.Adapter = childAdaptor;
             // call method : setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren after you set Adapter
            Utility.setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(childView);
        }


        return listItem;

    }
}
```

The effect is : 
[image]

Comment: Glad to help.Happy coding.